# GNU Parallel and Solaris 11

Tags: parallel-processing, solaris

I'm trying to run a number of jobs using the parallel command in Solaris 11 with the following command:

```
find . -name "job*" | parallel -P 64 :::
```

The CWD has script files job1...job256 that I need to run. These files have a few variable definitions and run fine by running:
    ./job1 &
    ./job2 &
etc

However, I do get the following error from gnu parallel when I run the command:

```
/usr/bin/bash: 1: command not found
...
/usr/bin/bash: 1: command not found
```

256 times

These procedure runs fine in my Debian box but not in my Solaris 11 + SPARC box.

Can anyone please point out to a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more details, because with the information you've provided the only answer you'll get will return similar data: "Something's broken."

Comment: Does --dry-run give what you expect? Does the tutorial work as described (`man parallel_tutorial`)? Are you sure the parallel on Solaris is GNU Parallel?

Comment: Andrew: Right now I'm trying to run the easiest case possible. The scripts job1...job256 are simply scripts with a single line -> echo "hello world!". Ole: Im running GNU parallel. I even compiled and ran the latest version from the GNU website and gives me the same result. --dry-run does give me the expected output. The tutorial seems to miss behave as well.

Comment: @Leonus -- Try removing the "!" from your output, so that bash doesn't try to interpret it as a reference to a previous command.

Comment: If 'parallel ::: echo' fails append the output of 'parallel -Dall ::: echo'. If that also fails: Follow 'REPORTING BUGS' in 'man parallel'.

Comment: I'm getting this when I use -Dall->>>>> $VAR2 = bless( {
                 'max_jobs_running' => undef,
                 'jobs_running' => 0,
                 'swap_activity_file' => '/export/home/alejandr/.parallel/tmp/swap_activity-1668-:',
                 'string' => ':',
                 'loadavg_file' => '/export/home/alejandr/.parallel/tmp/loadavg-1668-:',
                 'control_path_dir' => undef,

parallel: Error: Cannot open input file `ll': No such file or directory. And I bunch of numbers I cannot fit in here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your problem, but your question had google juice for me and maybe I can help people with the same problem I had.

It was the first time I used GNU parallel, and I set PARALLEL=1 on my bash script as a flag you could use to enable parallel tests. When I ran it, I saw your error message. Even when I stripped down my test command to a simple echo. But outside this bash script the error wouldn't occur. Hmmm.

PARALLEL=2 caused "2: command not found".

Turns out, this is read by GNU parallel.

From the man page:

```
$PARALLEL
      The environment variable $PARALLEL will be used as default options for GNU parallel. If the variable
      contains special shell characters (e.g. $, *, or space) then these need to be to be escaped with \.
```

And `1` can be interpreted as an argument to GNU parallel. It doesn't start with a dash, so it is interpreted as the command.

Comment: I ended up getting rid of Solaris 11 and installing Debian 7. Unfortunately I could not afford more time debugging the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yup, I had exactly this problem, spent hours trying to figure out what the hell was wrong. I would consider it a bug that parallel doesn't validate the options and instead, somehow, prepends it to the command to be executed. I used `--plain`to ignore the PARALLEL variable. Thanks.